# Use protocol relative urls with Django loggin

Tags: django, facebook, https, django-authentication, facebook-canvas

I'm developing a game that is recently running in facebook canvas.

For loggin I use [Django auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/), but, while it works fine in my page, in facebook canvas it doesn't. The reason is that [Django auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) automatically uses `http`, so I get this errors:

Chrome:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://apps.facebook.com/****/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://****.herokuapp.com/register/?next=/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Firefox:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://****.herokuapp.com/login/"
```

So, how can I make [Django auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) use relative urls so if the request is made from a `https` connection it uses `https`?

**EDIT:**

In firefox I also get this message (hope it helps):

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) iframe
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Django uses only relative urls, are you sure the problem isn't in your canvas settings in Facebook? you should give it the https url to your site

Comment: it looks like here you are giving Facebook the http url to start from: `'http://****.herokuapp.com/register/?next=/'`